# Cordova hot reloading on device without Ionic

Tags: javascript, cordova, ios-simulator

I'm using Cordova without Ionic or any other Framework. My problem is that I don't find any hot reload features or plugins for Cordova without using Ionic. Is there any solution to live reload on the iOS simulator without any frameworks?

Comment: https://github.com/nparashuram/cordova-plugin-browsersync

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've implemented a custom way of 'hot reloading' in Cordova. I don't know how original it is but it works well for my needs.
In broad lines it works like this: in development mode a static webserver is started and cordova is instructed that the content is the url of this server: `<content src="http://10.0.3.2:8080" />`.

The static server also listens to changes in the assets (js/css/html) and auto reloads. We use gulp connect (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect) to achieve this.

In production mode you have to compile the assets and instruct cordova to use the regular static file to load your app.

Details:

In *cordova.xml* this is the line that tells cordova where to start the app:

```
<content src="index.html" />
```

So this has to be replaced with a 'dynamic' version that would allow hot reload. I achieved this by using `gulp-connect` which starts a static file server.

```
  gulp.task('connect', function () {
    return connect.server({
      root: 'www',
      livereload: true,
      fallback: 'www/index.html',
      https: false
    });
  });
```

I created two tasks which switch the cordova configuration in development and in production:

```
  // Development
  // adds the localhost(on the emulator as 10.0.3.2) as
  // the content source for the cordova app
  gulp.task('cordova-dev-server-android', function () {
    return gulp.src(['config.xml'])
      .pipe(replace(/(<content src=\")(.+)(\" \/>)/g, "$1http://10.0.3.2:8080$3"))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
  });

  // Production
  // adds the static file as
  // the content source for the cordova app
  gulp.task('cordova-static-file', function () {
    return gulp.src(['config.xml'])
      .pipe(replace(/(<content src=\")(.+)(\" \/>)/g, "$1index.html$3"))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
  });
```

One important thing you have to ensure that the Cordova javascript files are accessible by the development web server. Again, I achieved this with two tasks for development/production.

```
  // Development
  // Creates symlinks for the devserver
  // so the app has access to cordova files
  gulp.task('create-cordova-symlink-android', ['remove-cordova-symlink'], function () {
    return gulp.src('')
      .pipe(exec('ln -sv ../platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js www'))
      .pipe(exec.reporter())
      .pipe(exec('ln -sv ../platforms/android/assets/www/cordova_plugins.js www'))
      .pipe(exec.reporter())
      .pipe(exec('ln -sv ../platforms/android/assets/www/plugins www'))
      .pipe(exec.reporter());
  }); 


  // Production
  // Removes symlinks for production
  // see create-cordova-symlink-android
  gulp.task('remove-cordova-symlink', function () {
    var options = {
      continueOnError: true
    };
    return gulp.src('')
      .pipe(exec('rm www/cordova.js', options))
      .pipe(exec('rm www/cordova_plugins.js', options))
      .pipe(exec('rm -Rf www/plugins', options));
  });
```

I am using gulp here but this can be implemented using any task runner, and of course for other platforms you have to modify this code a bit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ilteris I added some more details

Comment: Thank you this is great Ionut!

Comment: Thanks for this!  I was able to follow this example and get my Reactjs app, created with Create React App, live reloading on Android.  For now I am just modifying the config.xml content src manually as well as manually creating the symlinks.  In this starter project the /public folder is where webpack is configured to serve from, so I placed the symlinks there.

Comment: sorry for the dummies question. Where should i put this code? and how can i differentiate between dev & prod? and should I invoke it by a post-build script or something? (Using ReactJS + Cordova)