# Cordova + react with hot reload while development mode

Tags: reactjs, cordova, webpack

I found this question [Cordova with Create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336924/cordova-with-create-react-app).

Am I able to achieve live-reloading while I'm in development mode and app is running in android emulator? I'm scared that I have to build the app everytime I wanna to see changes.

Is cordova able to watch react-app which run in development mode and read source from `index.js` listening for changes?

Let's say that I want to achieve something like this:

1. create cordova project.
2. create react project inside of /www folder (or any other folder that will work with my use-case...).
3. run `cordova run android` from root to run application in Android Simulator and `npm start` from /www directory.
4. cordova should be able to listen for changes and live-reload react app inside Android emulator.
5. **I need to able to access cordova instance inside react code to use plugins, etc.**

I've found some webpack-server-dev (using webpack v1...) related solutions but none of them seems to be working and I need to restart `cordova run android` command to see changes in the code. Otherwise these templates doesn't provide functionality to enable access to the cordova plugins instance during development mode

> So is really `npm build` followed by `cordova run android` only way to develop cordova + react app??

Note 1: I would like to use SQLite cordova plguin so development in browser-only mode and then building the application for android/ios once its done is not my case I think. Do you have any suggestions please?

Note 2: I can't use react-native as I need to use openlayers maps lib.

*Thanks you so much for your answers!*

Answer (score 5):

1. Run webpack-dev-server with `--host 0.0.0.0` to make it accessible from outside
2. Change your config.xml and make `<content src="..." />` point to your local-IP address and your dev-port, e.g. `<content src="http://192.168.0.2:3000/" />`
3. Add a whitelist entry (refer to cordova whitelist-plugin documentation for more details): e.g. `<allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.2:3000/*" />`
4. If you need native functionalities via `cordova`, you need to make all cordova and cordova-plugin javascript files available in your dev-server. Please check this answer as well (symlink part): https://stackoverflow.com/a/46545408/1930339

Comment: Thank you! hope it will help to somebody :) I switched to react-native